# Efficient implementation of MINUS in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables both having a column called key and I like to something like `SELECT key FROM table1 MINUS SELECT key FROM table2` in MySQL (5.6.19). (table1 contains about 1.5 million rows, table2 about 100,000.) The things I tried are

```
SELECT key FROM table1 WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM table2);
SELECT a.key FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b USING (key) WHERE b.key IS NULL;
SELECT a.key FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.key=b.key WHERE b.key IS NULL;
```

But both are unbelievable inefficient! (After waiting for a result for the first query I stopped it and started all queries in parallel during the night. The first one took insane 12 hours 51 min, the second and third one 7 hours 32 min and 7 hours 53 min, respectively).

How can this be done efficiently? Is it only a problem of MySQL or of all SQL implementations in general? (In case of importance: key is of type char(32), table1 contains many more columns (also a lot of strings), table2 apart from key only some integer columns). Thank you very much for any hint in advance!

@Steve Rukuts: The `EXPLAIN SELECT a.key FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.key=b.key WHERE b.key IS NULL;` gives:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                                           |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | index | NULL          | Key  | 97      | NULL | 1372811 | Using index                                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | index | NULL          | Key  | 33      | NULL |  101580 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What indexes do you have defined (specifically are `table1.Key` and `table2.key` indexed)?

Comment: I would expect the `NOT IN` method to be very slow. I would not expect your third query to be slow however. I suspect you have an indexing problem. It is also possible that there is something else wrong. Perform `EXPLAIN SELECT a.key FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.key=b.key WHERE b.key IS NULL;` and let us know the result.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Whats the purpose of that query?

Comment: Maybe the name `key` is a little bit misleading... I have renamed it before... Both tables have a primary key called `id`. The `key`-field is a unique key. The result of the EXPLAIN SELECT gives select_type "SIMPLE", type "index", possible_keys "NULL", key "KEY", key_len "97"  /"33", ref "NULL", rows "1372811" / "100889" and Extra "Using index" / "Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"

Comment: There results of explain are in the order for table1=a / table2=b.

Comment: have you tried `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.id = b.id)`?

Comment: @1010: I just tried `SELECT key FROM table1 a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 b WHERE a.key = b.key);` but 30min there still was no answer... (I guess you meant `a.key=b.key`... the id's of both tables don't have anything in common...)